# Reading negative numbers in a column

Tags: ssis

I'm using SSIS to separate good data from unusable date. In order to do that I used derived columns, script task and conditional split where I assigned certain conditions. One of the conditions I need to apply is that none of the numbers in one column cannot be negative. I'm guessing that the best way to solve this would be using conditional split, but I cannot get it to work. I'm new to SSIS, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have an Expression like

```
[MyCaseSensitiveColumnName] < 0
```

and then name the output path something like `BadData_NegativeValue`

From the comments

> that is what I did before, but I'm getting an error saying that The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_I4" are incompatible for binary operator ">"

That error message indicates that you are attempting to compare a unicode string (DT_WSTR) and an integer (DT_I4) and that the expression language does not allow it.

To resolve this type incompatibility, you would need to first convert the value of `MyCaseSensitiveColumnName` from DT_WSTR to an integer.

I'd likely add a Derived Column Component to my data flow and create a new column called `MyCaseSensitiveColumnNameAsInteger` with an expression like

```
(DT_I4) [MyCaseSensitiveColumnName]
```

Now, that *may* be perilous depending on the quality of your source data. I don't know why you are pulling numeric data in as a string. If there could be non whole numbers in the data set, then we will need to check before making the cast. If there are NULLs in that dataset, those too may cause issues.

That would result in our conditional split check becoming

```
[MyCaseSensitiveColumnNameAsInteger] < 0
```

Comment: that is what I did before, but I'm getting an error saying that "The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_I4" are incompatible for binary operator ">". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator."

Comment: Updated my answer